# Referencing an aliased expression in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query and I would like to use a where clause on the expression `Percentage` which contains an aggregate:

```
SELECT Percentage = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - COUNT(some_irrelevant_column))
FROM Product P INNER JOIN Item PD
ON PD.ProductId = P.ProductId
WHERE Percentage < 50;
```

This yields the following error:

> Invalid column name 'Percentage'.

Comment: It's a good practice to post the error you are getting. It helps people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Don't you want to select another field? If you're returning one aggregate result in the query limiting makes no sense.

Comment: @GoatCO : I have other fields too , I just simplified the query to only include the part I am having problem with, I thought it would be easy to read this way

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.ExceptionCode  != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100)) as Percentage
from Product as P
    inner join Item as PD on PD.ProductId = P.ProductId
)
select Percentage from cte where Percentage < 50
```

It's possible to use [subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but for me CTE is more readable

```
select *
from (
    select CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.ExceptionCode  != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100)) as Percentage
from Product as P
    inner join Item as PD on PD.ProductId = P.ProductId
) as A
where A.Percentage < 50
```

It also possible to solve this with [having](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx), but it would not be very readable or maintainable:

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.ExceptionCode != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100)) as Percentage
from Product as P
    inner join Item as PD on PD.ProductId = P.ProductId
having CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.ExceptionCode != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100)) < 50
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that both the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses are parsed *before* the `SELECT` list. This has nothing to do with aggregates. The same thing will happen if you have a very simple expression, such as:

```
SELECT a = 1 + 2 WHERE a = 3;
```

Picture that SQL Server actually reads that backwards: "For the rows where a = 3, return the expression 1 + 2, and label it a." This doesn't work because a doesn't exist yet in order to check if a = 3. I talk a little bit about why this is on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19762/why-is-the-select-clause-listed-first/19768#19768) and [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in/21966#21966) over on dba.stackexchange.com (there are some other answers there worth reading, as well).

Therefore you cannot create an alias in the `SELECT` list and then reference the alias in other clauses (`ORDER BY` is the only one where this works, and even there you will find exceptions). The workarounds are to use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT a FROM (SELECT 1 + 2) AS x(a) WHERE a = 3;

;WITH x(a) AS (SELECT 1 + 2) SELECT a FROM x WHERE a = 3;
```

Or repeat the expression (usually not desirable):

```
SELECT a = 1 + 2 WHERE 1 + 2 = 3;
```

Comment: @Roman that's definitely a subjective thing. I find outer apply to be far less intuitive and more complicated than a CTE or subquery. I typically reserve apply for usage with UDFs.

Comment: sry just seen that I've deleted my comment somehow, I was on mobile :( the comment was smth like "Great answer, Aaron, I also like to use outer apply to precalculate values so I can use it in Select and where clause".

Answer (score 2):

To filter a result set based on an aggregate function, you need to include it in the `HAVING` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause..

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference